# When I try to run nodemon from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, nodemon

When I try to run nodemon from terminal it's just throwing back as [...\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. ] How can I overcome this error and solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try to do these steps in order:

1. run the terminal as administrator and then try the command
2. If the above doesn't work, then type this command `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`
3. As a final resort, type this command if none of the steps work - `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: Thank you the 1st step help me. What was my problem is that I was not running the terminal in administrator or any other?

Comment: As an administrator, you have access to running scripts that may change the machine's state, unlike if you run the terminal normally, as a normal user, who is not allowed to modify the machine's state or its execution policies.

Comment: If your doubt has been cleared and the error has been resolved, please close this thread by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the execution policy of your system.

Running `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted` should solve your problem. Remember to run the command in an **administrative powershell**

You can view your current execution policy by running `Get-ExecutionPolicy –List` in powershell

For more info, you can visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2)